# describe the ring $R=M_2(\Bbb F)$, where $\Bbb F$ is a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let the ring $R=M_2(\Bbb F)$, where $\Bbb F$ is a field.

1. What is the description $R^*$.
2. Find order $(M_2(\Bbb Z_3))^*$.

Comment: see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?lq=1) for editing your posts.

Comment: What * does mean??

Comment: I was studing for abstract algebra prevous exams and i found this question

Comment: Thank you Jean ,how about 2??

Comment: Meaning of *  ...

Comment: I doubt the intention of the first question is that you just supply the definition. Are you familiar with the determinant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Given a ring $A$, $A^\star$ is the group of invertible elements of $A$ (that is, the group of [units](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_%28ring_theory%29)). Here, they are invertible matrices, that is matrices $M=\left(\begin{matrix} a & b\\c & d\end{matrix}\right)$ with $ad-bc\neq0$, because in a field, every nonzero element has an inverse.

   The inverse of $M$ is then $\dfrac{1}{ad-bc}\left(\begin{matrix} d & -c\\-b & a\end{matrix}\right)$.
2. It's easier to count singular matrices. Since $\Bbb Z_3$ is a field (with three elements), equation $ad-bc=0$ has always a solution in $a$ if $d\neq0$, thus for each $d \in \{1,2\}$, you have $3^2$ solutions, so $18$. And if $d=0$, any $a$ is valid, and you must have $bc=0$, thus $b=0$ or $c=0$ (that is, $3+3-1=5$ solutions for each $a$, so $5\times3$ total solutions when $d=0$). Therefore, there are $18+15=33$ matrices which are *not* invertible, among $3^4=81$ matrices, thus $|R^\star|=81-33=48$. That is $GL_2(3)$ is a group of order $48$.

---

You can generalize the above result, to a field with $n$ elements (where necessarily $n=p^k$ for some prime $p$ and some integer $k\geq0$).

- The equation $ad-bc$ has a solution in $a$ for each $d\neq0$, that is $n-1$ values of $d$ and $n^2$ values for $b$ and $c$, thus $n^2(n-1)$ such matrices.
- When $d=0$, all $n$ values of $a$ are valid, and you must have $b=0$ or $c=0$. This amounts to $n(2n-1)$ solutions. *(pay attention to the fact that $2n$ instead of $2n-1$ would count $b=c=0$ twice)*

All in all, there are $n^2(n-1)+n(2n-1)$ singular matrices, and the number of regular matrices is thus

$$n^4-n^2(n-1)-n(2n-1)=n^4-n^3-n^2+n=n[n^2(n-1)-(n-1)]=n(n-1)(n^2-1)$$

Therefore, the group $GL(2,n)$ has order $n(n-1)(n^2-1)$.

But notice the formula is valid for a group of matrices with coefficients in a finite *field*. More generally, you may also consider matrices over a ring, such as $\Bbb Z/4$, which is not a field. Then the matrix ring has also a group of units, but it's more complicated to compute its order. The determinant has then to be a *unit* of the ring of coefficients.

Comment: Thank you very much jean-Claude Arbqut

Comment: -1 For such a complete solution.

Comment: @Jean-Claude Arbaut +1 For such a complete solution.

Comment: To maybe add a little context, this user (Sara) has been posting a lot of problem statements recently without shown effort, despite many comments advising her to show effort. It's debatable here what the right course of action is, but hopefully (for the sake of Sara's education, anyway) the derivative of effort shown is positive and the number of complete-answers-on-a-platter trail off.